# Z-index in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a map and when hover effect on a region of the map that is below the yellow line and the circle, the last ones disappear. How can I solve this problem?

http://jsfiddle.net/ot21n9qx/

```
       var arc = g.append("path")
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", "yellow")
        .style("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("d", "M" + pathOrigin[0] + "," + pathOrigin[1] + " Q" + svgPoint[0] + "," + pathOrigin[1] + " " + svgPoint[0] + "," + svgPoint[1]);

      var circleSize = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 0.5, 1])
        .range([4, 10, 4]);
```

Comment: What is your problem? I don't see anything, out of the ordinary, that disappears.

Comment: the line yellow. you should make the hovering effect over the line yellow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SVG` does not have a Z order but it draws the objects in the order they are created. You just need to create the `path` and `circle` after you create the highlight regions.

Here is the forked fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/o00fzgaf/1/

Comment: great...
But if I then want to add more circles dynamically ... what should I do?

Comment: You can always add svg elements  and keep their opacity to 0: `.style("opacity", 0)'. When you need the element to be visible, just change the opacity. You can also update their location.

Comment: You should add a wrapper g for your circles. You now add everything to the same g. Use your browser inspector to see the g-grouping